# Llora que llora

Tags: gramática

From the children’s book “Antes de ser libres” by [Julia Álvarez](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julia_%C3%81lvarez), there’s this sentence:

> Pobre tía Mari estaba llora que llora.

I understand that the poor aunt is crying and crying. But I don’t think I’ve seen that construction before, although it seems to be a song title. By the way, I recommend the book for intermediate readers. It’s a historical novel from the point of view of a 12 year old girl regarding the resistance against Trujillo in the Dominican Republic.

Comment: By the way, have you read "La fiesta del chivo" by Mario Vargas Llosa? It's a great book also centered in that resistance.

Comment: Thank you do much RubioRic. I’ve added "La fiesta del chivo" to my Kindle library. It will be more of a challenge to read, but looks to be worth the effort.

Comment: I think so. One of the greatest modern books in Spanish. And you know that you can come here if you got any doubt. :-)

Answer (score 5):

You can find that as an specific meaning associated with conjunction **[que](https://dle.rae.es/que)** in the DLE

> 16. conj. Precedida y seguida de la tercera persona de indicativo de un mismo verbo, denota el progreso o eficacia de la acción de este
>     verbo. Corre que corre; porfía que porfía.

Definition is a bit obscure even for native speakers: *it denotes the progress or efficacy of the action from this verb*, the one that is followed and preceded by **que**.

I'm my opinion, it has got the same meaning that you get if "que" is replaced by "y" (what you mentioned about crying and crying) having then a sense of repetition and endlessness [repetición indefinida].

You can check that nuance of **[y](https://dle.rae.es/y)** in the DLE

> 4. conj. copulat. Denota idea de repetición indefinida, precedida y seguida por una misma palabra. Días y días. Cartas y cartas.

Comment: Thank you!  Since it says 3rd person, does that mean I would say: "Yo estaba llora que llora"?  That seems odd.

Comment: @Bekah Yes, it seems odd but that sentence is idiomatic.